# Nth number of fibonacci

Tags: python

I am learning python.  I am working on printing the Nth number of the Fibonacci sequence.  I am reading a solution but I don't understand it.  Could someone please explain how this solution works.  I don't understand why it is recursively returning the next term and the current term?  Shouldn't it recursively add the previous two terms?  Where is terms defined as a list?  Thanks for any help.

```
def fib(N):
    """
    Recursively return the next term and the current term in the Fibonacci
    sequence.
    
    """
    if N == 1:
        return [1, 0]
    else:
        terms = fib(N - 1)
        terms = [terms[0] + terms[1], terms[0]]
        return terms


def validate_positive_integer():
    """
    Ask the user for input and only return when a positive integer under
    500 is given.
    """
    while True:
        s = raw_input("Which term in the Fibonacci sequence you want to see? ")
        try:
            N = int(s)
            if N >= 500:
                print "Enter a number smaller than 500."
            elif N > 0:
                return N
            else:
                print "Enter a positive integer."
        except ValueError:
            print "Enter a positive integer."


def main():
    N = validate_positive_integer()
    print fib(N)[1]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `terms` is defined as a list in  the base case: `return [1, 0]`  and here: `terms = [terms[0] + terms[1], terms[0]]` which is also where you add the previous two terms. The reason the returns both values is so you only need to call `fib(N - 1)` to get the terms to add rather than the *much* less efficient: `fib(N - 1) + fib(N - 2)`.

Comment: Hi I entered 5 and printed list and it looks like it starts at 1,1.  It seems like when five is entered list should start at 4,4 or something.  How does list start at 1,1 and then increase it seems like n-1 would make it decrease.

Answer (score 1):

If you let `F(n)` denote the `n`th Fibonacci number, you'll see that `fib(n)` returns both `F(n+1)` and `F(n)`. That gives you the desired Fibonacci number as well as precomputing the value that `fib(n+1)` will need to return `F(n+2)` and `F(n+1)`.

Answer (score 0):

`terms` is being defined as a list here, `terms = [terms[0] + terms[1], terms[0]`, using the values from `terms = fib(N - 1)`. Since the sequence is defined as the sum of the previous two terms, the two previously returned terms are added. Comment any more questions here

Comment: I printed terms and it looks like it starts out at [1,1] and then increases.   For example when I enter 5 into the program why does it start at 1,1 and not 4.  It seems like fib(N) should start at N-1 which would be 4 and not 1,1.  I thought terms would start at 5 and then decrease by 1.